# Javascript ~ SailsJs Action not defined

Tags: javascript, sails.js

**The Problem**

so I'm editing a crud application to have confirmation before delete and I created a javascript function to do that but I'm getting the following error in my cmd and on the "show" page

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  ReferenceError:
>   C:\Users\Micha\Documents\intelligente-vraagbaak\views\answer\show.ejs:176
>       174|         if (c){
>       175|             console.log("done");
>       176|             window.location.href = "action/delete/<%=action.id %>"
>       177|         }
>       178|
>       179|         else{
>
> action is not defined

**The Code**

This is part of the code where the delete should happen,

```
<td class="actions" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
                        <a href="/actionbrand/create/<%= action.id %>"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default"
                           data-toggle="tooltip"
                           data-original-title="Toevoegen"><i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="/action/show/<%= action.id %>"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing"
                           data-toggle="tooltip"
                           data-original-title="Bekijk"><i class="icon wb-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="/action/edit/<%= action.id %>"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default"
                           data-toggle="tooltip"
                           data-original-title="Bewerk"><i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <form id="deleteAction" action="javascript:Delete()" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    data-original-title="Verwijder"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% }) %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function Delete(){
        let c = confirm('U staat op het punt een actie te verwijderen, klik op "ok" om hier mee door te gaan');
        if (c){
            console.log("done");
            window.location.href = "action/delete/<%=action.id %>"
        }

        else{
            console.log("failed")
            window.location.href = "/answer/show/<%= answer.id %>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

**What I Don't Get**

I don't get this error because I'm using the variable action all over this page and there are no errors what so ever but when I use it in my function I get an error. What am I doing wrong? any help would be nice (sorry for my english I'm not a native speaker)

## EDIT

**Where Is "Action" Comming From**

Action is an alias for all the actions I have, defined in a foreach loop above the `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`

```
 <%- answer.actions.length === 0 ? "<tr><td>No results</td></tr>" : null %>
            <% _.each(answer.actions, action => { %>
```

Comment: is `action` something you declare inside a loop or something in the `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` ?

Comment: @MjZac I updated the question

Comment: You are closing the loop at `</tr> <% }) %> </tbody>`. Hence `action` is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mjZac is right in his comment - `action` is only defined in side your loop, so it is undefined outside the loop.

What you need is to pass in the action (or just `action.id`) information to your method. The way you are set up, I think you can do that by just adding it as a parameter to your method call.

```
<% _.each(answer.actions, action => { %>
    <td class="actions" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
        <!-- some other stuff... -->
        <form class="deleteAction" action="javascript:Delete(<%= action.id %>)" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Verwijder"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
    </td>
<% }) %>

<script>
    function Delete(actionId){
        let c = confirm('U staat op het punt een actie te verwijderen, klik op "ok" om hier mee door te gaan');
        if (c){
            console.log("done");
            window.location.href = "action/delete/" + actionId;
        }
    }
</script>
```

To sum up, the template adds the action id to the `Delete()` method call in each `tr`, then the script uses that id to generate it's url in pure javascript (no templating tags involved).